# Iterate sub directories and create new files in sub-directory

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to create new files(.m4a) in each sub directory based on a each file(.mp3) in sub directory.For some reason the new file is getting created in root directory of batch file placed.

```
for /R %%a in ("*.mp3") do "C:\Users\bin\ffmpeg" -i "%%a" %%~na.m4a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
for /R %%a in ("*.mp3") do "C:\Users\bin\ffmpeg" -i "%%a" "%%~dpna.m4a"
```

You give the new file as only a filename, but that creates the file in the current working direction, which is the root directory of the batch file, unless cd or pushd are executed.

By giving ffmpeg the drive+path too, it should put the new files in the same directory as the mp3 fiel.

Comment: Above Command worked only if folder names under the directory doesn't have space.How to handle if the folder name has space?

Comment: edited to handle spaces, can't believe I forgot to double quote that